# raspberrypi et opencv, missing libhdf5-103

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to install opencv in a raspberrypi 4. The os is raspbiam. The content of `/etc/apt/source.list.d/raspi.list`  is:

`deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main`

When I try this search:
`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-cache search libhdf5-103`

I get:

`libhdf5-103 - Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - runtime files - serial version`

if I understand, this result tell us that libhdf5-103 is inside.
However when I try to install it using `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-103`:

I get:

`Err :1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libhdf5-103 armhf 1.10.4+repack-10 404  Not Found`

I have installed other libs correctly but libhdf5-103 is impossible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a possible solution:
I have changed the raspi.list file using another mirror:

`deb http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian buster main`

It seems that now the lib is installed correctly....